# Redisが起動しないのです。cenos7 php7 vagrant virtrualboxの環境

Tags: php, centos, vagrant, virtualbox, redis

こんにちは。どうぞ叡智をお貸しくださいm(__)m
Redis2.8をyumでインストールして起動させようとしていますが、起動が途中で止まっているみたいなのです。

インストール環境は、VagrantとVirtualBoxを使用して、CentOS7.1.15にapache2.4を入れています。
virturalボックスのコンソールの設定は調整して
[VagrantのVirtualBox](https://gyazo.com/2f567a145694043e4f3369f63300895a)←メモリーは2GBにしています。

サーバーコンソール：

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl start redis
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo systemctl status redis
● redis.service - Redis persistent key-value database
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/redis.service.d
           └─limit.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 月 2016-04-25 20:26:43 JST; 2s ago
  Process: 3685 ExecStop=/usr/bin/redis-shutdown (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 3684 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis.conf --daemonize no (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3684 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Redis persistent key-value database.
 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Redis persistent key-value database...
 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: redis.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain redis-shutdown[3685]: Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: redis.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit redis.service entered failed state.
 4月 25 20:26:43 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: redis.service failed.
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

こんな具合に出力されております。
どう調整したらうごかせるでしょうか？
どうぞ重ねて教えを請いたいとお願い申し上げますです。

Answer (score -2):

**結果報告**
コンソールで

```
>redis-sever
```

と入力して実行。redisサービスが動いている画面になります。
そのままにしておいて、もう一つコンソールを起動して、

```
>redis-cli ping
PONG
```

これで起動することが確認できていました。なのでインストールの失敗はしていないようでした。
サービス側で[Ctrl]+c を実行しサービスを停止。

/var/log/redis/redis.log
この内容を確認して、そこに書かれているコマンド
'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1'これを実行し

```
>sudo sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1
>sudo servicectl start redis.service
>servicectl status redis
```

いけました。
そしてさらにそこに書かれている、
'/etc/sysctl.conf'

```
vm.overcommit_memory = 1
```

を記載。
virtualBox(Vagrant)を抜けて、

```
>vi Vagrantfile
```

これでメモリーを増加させておいた設定をコメントアウト

```
>vagrant reload
```

デフォルトのメモリー空間が2048MBのままになっているのを確認（一度増やすとそのままになるんだ〜偶然知りました）
vagrant sshで中に入り

```
>servicectl status redis
```

いけてました。

Quitaにまとめておこうかな。

Comment: たぶんメモリ関係なんでしょうね。ログに記載されている設定をきちんとすればいけました。
/etc/sysctl.conf
    vm.overcommit_memory = 1

Comment: box を destroyして再作成したら640MBでも動いてる。う〜んなんでかな？